# Google Maps API3 info window - xml file

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have xml file:

```
marker ...........
marker ...........
marker ...........
```

I want to run specific info window (the first or last) automatically use: google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click'); but it always runs info window on the last marker.
I can use marker numbering for example marker1, marker2, marker3 but then the other functions do not work.

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

markers are numbered starting at 0.

To pull the info for marker1 you need to access info0, for marker3 it's info2 etc.